# How to add Geolocation in Mapbox

Tags: flutter, mapbox

I was wondering if it is possible to get user location in Mapbox in flutter. 
I tried using  geolocator but i don't know how to put the result of geolocator and apply it on mapbox.
Here is my current code.

```
 body: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
          FlutterMap(
            options: new MapOptions( 
                center: new LatLng(51.5074, 0.1278), 
                minZoom: 10.0),
            layers: [
              new TileLayerOptions(
                  urlTemplate:
                  "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/zion21/ck20r0qmi4gg51co4w3uvjfob/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiemlvbjIxIiwiYSI6ImNrMjBlMHFtMjB4NDQzbXE4N3FqcGVibzEifQ.9d-UxqgnIdB1WeDHKfwp-A",
                  additionalOptions: {
                    'accessToken':
                    '--',
                    'id': 'mapbox.mapbox-streets-v7'
                  }),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [mapbox_gl plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/mapbox_gl) you can use the `myLocationEnabled` property of MapboxMap to display a blue dot at the user's location like this:

```
MapboxMap(
    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: LatLng(51.5074, 0.1278),),
    myLocationEnabled: true,
),
```

You can also change the appearance of the MyLocationLayer using the `myLocationTrackingMode` property.

Comment: is it possible to keep it recorded in the background?